# Extremes of integration with box normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, quantum-interpretations

In order to be able to normalize the plane wave we confine our system to a box with a finite volume $V$ which we take to be infinity at the end of the calculations. This box is chosen so that it is square and has side $l$.

So, when I perform the box normalization, which are the extremes of integration I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Typically we would define our box to go from $-\ell/2$ to $\ell/2$. One reason for doing this is that it makes it easy to consider the parity of functions under reflection about the origin, where $x\mapsto -x$. Another reason is that at the end of our calculations, we simply take $\ell \rightarrow \infty$ in all of our expressions.

It is of course possible to study a system in a box which goes from $0$ to $\ell$, but then the parity operator becomes more annoying ($x \mapsto \ell - x$) and the final limit is similarly annoying because $\ell\rightarrow \infty$ would yield the half space $(x\geq 0)$ (unless that's what you want, of course).

Comment: ok perfect, thanks a lot